# How to create a square dataframe/matrix given 3 columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, reformatting

I am struggling to figure out how to develop a square matrix given a format like

```
a a 0
a b 3
a c 4
a d 12
b a 3 
b b 0
b c 2
...
```

To something like:

```
  a b c d e
a 0 3 4 12 ... 
b 3 0 2 7 ... 
c 4 3 0 .. .
d 12 ...  
e . ..
```

in pandas. I developed a method which I thinks works but takes forever to run because it has to iterate through each column and row for every value starting from the beginning each time using for loops. I feel like I'm definitely reinventing the wheel here. This also isnt realistic for my dataset given how many columns and rows there are. Is there something similar to R's cast function in python which can do this significantly faster?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'a', 0],
                   ['a', 'b', 3],
                   ['a', 'c', 4],
                   ['a', 'd', 12],
                   ['b', 'a', 3],
                   ['b', 'b', 0],
                   ['b', 'c', 2]], columns=['X','Y','Z'])

print(df.pivot(index='X', columns='Y', values='Z'))
```

yields

```
Y    a    b    c     d
X                     
a  0.0  3.0  4.0  12.0
b  3.0  0.0  2.0   NaN
```

Here, `index='X'` tells `df.pivot` to use the column labeled `'X'` as the index, and `columns='Y'` tells it to use the column labeled `'Y'` as the column index.

See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) for more on `pivot` and other reshaping methods.

---

Alternatively, you could use [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print(pd.crosstab(index=df.iloc[:,0], columns=df.iloc[:,1], 
                  values=df.iloc[:,2], aggfunc='sum'))
```

Unlike `df.pivot` which expects each `(a1, a2)` pair to be unique, `pd.crosstab`
(with `agfunc='sum'`) will aggregate duplicate pairs by summing the associated
values. Although there are no duplicate pairs in your posted example, specifying
how duplicates are supposed to be aggregated is required when the `values`
parameter is used.

Also, whereas `df.pivot` is passed column labels, `pd.crosstab` is passed
array-likes (such as whole columns of `df`). `df.iloc[:, i]` is the `i`th column
of `df`.

Comment: Given the orignal DF, the answer could be confusing to those not yet comfortable with pandas syntax. The parameters given inside the df.pivot are the names of the original df columns, not the indicies. So be sure to read it as "The column named '0' as the index" and not "The first (0th) column is the index"

Comment: @JeffEllen: Good point. I've made an edit to hopefully make this clearer.